# c++: x / 60 = 2, but 60 / x = 0?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a music generator in C++, and I'm currently working on BPM. To get the amount of time to wait between notes, I'm using `60 / bpm`, but this evaluates to zero. I have checked to make sure that `bpm` is declared, and it is. Trying `60 / bpm` for some reason gives `2`. Why is this?

Comment: integer division rounds to nearest whole. Try changing one of the numbers to a double.

Comment: Use a `double` or a `float`. You would do `60.0 / bpm` instead.

Comment: I changed `bpm` to a `float`. Thank you!

Comment: @ryrich - integer division of non-negative numbers truncates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because 60 / 120 is 0 considering the constants are integral. (Inferring 120 from x / 60 = 2.) You will need to use 60.0 / x for example to get a floating point number as a result.